# Android, MediaRecorder to 3gp container video fails

Tags: android, video, multimedia

I am facing a problem recording a video with MediaRecorder. I need to register a video in H264 and save it in a 3gp container with extension mp4. I absolutely need this video format, because then I will open it with a native library that I can't directly modify for my own. I am using the following code, that normally works well. But with another tablet, the video is taken, but the format isn't the same (and the native library stops to work).

Inspecting the video proprieties I saw that the second video has a container "Quicktime" instead of "3gp":
[image]

And analysing the video's bytes, I found that the header isn't the 3gp's one.

What's wrong in the code?

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();

    recorder.setCamera(camera);

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setVideoSize(320, 240);

    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);

    recordingPath = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()
            + "/" + System.currentMillis();
    recorder.setOutputFile(recordingPath + ".mp4");

    recorder.setMaxDuration(50000); // 50 seconds
    recorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Approximately 5 megabytes
    recorder.setPreviewDisplay(recPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    recorder.start();
```

it seems like the *recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);* doesn't take effect

Thanks, Nico